# create download link between two asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, download

Lets say I have two applications as:
www.test.com/a 
 
www.test.com/b

In site b, I have a page set to download a pdf file. The page is called OpenBook.aspx, when I pass the bookId in the query string, it downloads the relevant file.

Here's the code to download this file from site b, by clicking on a link:

lbl.Text = "Report book {0}

is completed and ready for view. ";

Now this works within site B, but it obviously don't work within A. Because the path is set as www.test.com/a/Processing/OpenReportBook.aspx.....

I tried using the following:

```
 string downloadLocation =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString() + "/DataCenter/Processing/OpenReportBook.aspx?ReportID=";
                    Label2.Text = "Report book <a href='" + downloadLocation +
                                                                       + 948 +
                                                                       "'>{0}</a> is completed and ready for view. ";
```

But still, the path is set relative to site A, when you click it from site A.

Can someone please explain how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString()` .

Instead  give the second url in web.config as below

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="downloadurl" value="http://www.test.com/b" />
</appsetings>
```

And in your .cs file replace the folowing code

```
string downloadLocation =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString() + "/DataCenter/Processing/OpenReportBook.aspx?ReportID=";
                    Label2.Text = "Report book <a href='" + downloadLocation +
                                                                       + 948 +
                                                                       "'>{0}</a> is completed and ready for view. ";
```

with

```
string downloadLocation =    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[downloadurl"].ToString() + "/DataCenter/Processing/OpenReportBook.aspx?ReportID=";
                    Label2.Text = "Report book <a href='" + downloadLocation +
                                                                       + 948 +
                                                                       "'>{0}</a> is completed and ready for view. ";
```

i hope this may solve your problem.